# Search form query in URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a regular `POST` form for my search function. I currently have the following route:

Route::post('/search', 'PostController@search');

I get the form data using jQuery/AJAX:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/search',
        type: 'post',
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
            //
        },
        error: function(data)
        {
            //
        }
    });
});
```

However, when the results page is shown, it only shows `/search` in the URL without the user's query, like:

```
http://www.website.com/search
```

What I want is to do something like `/search/{user query here}`, like:

```
http://www.website.com/search/bob
```

Essentially, I want to be able to show the user's query within the URL.

How can I do this and how can I do this safely?

Comment: try using the redirect like `return Redirect::route('search', array('user' => {some query here}));`

Comment: You probably want to be running a GET query rather than a post query to achieve this. I don't think this will change the current URL though. e.g `http://www.website.com/search?q=bob`

Comment: @james he should use a route with a wildcard

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. Use normal form and give action as "user/{user_name}" when submit without using jQuery.
   For that add a route like that.

   Route::get('/search/{user_name}', 'PostController@show');
2. When your ajax success redirect it to the page "user/{user_name}"